# How do I recover specific parts of builds in a Minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have this creative Minecraft world where I build alot of stuff on. Specifically on my base design. And at one point suddenly what we worked on the last few days on for the base, just disappeard. The rest was still there. Basically the world traveled back in time for a couple of days. Please how do I fix this? How do I recover my Minecraft world? I have tried to restore saves in the save file, and it didn't work.

Comment: Is this a Minecraft realm? Because it happens sometimes. And unless you created backup of your world there's nothing you can do, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

You can't recover without a recovery file (*obviously*)

if you want to have recovery for only parts of a world, you can use schematic files and a schematic loader ([Litematica](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/litematica)) they are useful if you want to replicate something you built in your singleplayer world or recover parts of a world.

You can go watch a tutorial on YouTube that might help you out on this.
https://www.youtube.com/embed/KFzyNtyN8qI